# Get only newest records grouped by some value in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table in a SQL Server database containing the following data:

| ID | Date | CountryName | DimensionID | SomeValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 232 | 2020-12-28 | France | 10 | 4123 |
| 127 | 2020-07-14 | France | 10 | 753 |
| 239 | 2021-02-25 | France | 10 | 8634 |
| 129 | 2020-09-21 | France | 10 | 725 |
| 434 | 2021-08-20 | Italy | 10 | 832 |
| 430 | 2021-07-18 | Italy | 10 | 2534 |
| 119 | 2019-02-06 | Germany | 10 | 3645 |
| 123 | 2021-07-23 | Germany | 10 | 4634 |
| 141 | 2021-09-19 | Germany | 10 | 3968 |

Using Entity Framework Core 6, LinqToEntities obviously, I'm trying to get with LINQ only the latest, newest, record by country. From the above sample data I'd like to have the following subset:

| ID | Date | CountryName | DimensionID | SomeValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 239 | 2021-02-25 | France | 10 | 8634 |
| 434 | 2021-08-20 | Italy | 10 | 832 |
| 141 | 2021-09-19 | Germany | 10 | 3968 |

I can't see a way to filter this data without getting the whole results first from the database.

Is there a way to get this reduced dataset directly from the DB?

Comment: Code as in the duplicate works in EF-core as of v6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Table.GroupBy(a=>a.CountryName).Select(a=>a.OrderByDescending(a=>a.Date).FirstOrDefault());
```

It produces one SQL statement returning just the results you want